# copy linked list with random link in each node, each node has a variable，which randomly points to another node in the list

Tags: c++, algorithm, list, data-structures

**An interview question:**

> copy linked list with random link in each node, each node has a variable，which randomly 
>   points to another node in the list.

**My ideas:**

Iterate the list, copy each node and its pointed nodes by its variable and add a sentinel at the end and then do the same thing for each node.

In the new list, for each node i, separate each list ended with sentinel and use i's variable points to it.

It is not efficient in space. It is O(n^2) in time and space. 
Better ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can pinch ideas from e.g. Java 
Serialisation, which recognises when pointers point to nodes already serialised, so that it can serialise (and then deserialise) arbitrary structures reasonably efficiently. The spec, which you can download via a link at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/serialization/index.html, says that this is done but doesn't say exactly how - I suspect hash tables.

I think copying is a lot like this - you don't even need to know that some of the pointers make up a linked list. You could use a depth first search to traverse the graph formed by the nodes and their pointers, putting the location of each node in a hash table as you go, with the value the copied node. If the node is already present you don't need to do anything except make the pointer in the copied node point to the copy of the node pointed to as given by the hash table. If the node is not already present, create the copy, put the node in the hash table with the address of the copy as its value, and recursively copy the information in the node, and its pointers, into the newly made copy.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical interview question. You can find many answers by using Google. This is a link I think is good for understanding. But please read the comments too, there are some errors in the main body: [Copy a linked list with next and arbit pointer](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/1155)